# How to extract numeric vectors from R data frame string columns and save as columns (lists) with vectors

Tags: r, list, vector, data-conversion

Imagine a R data frame with numerous string columns that contain a chain of numerals (scientific notation) between some characters in each row. Here a simplified example:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:3,
             vec1 = c("[a-4.16121967e-02 b4.51207198e-02 c-7.89282843e-02 d4.02516453e-03]", 
                      "[a-7.52146867e-02 b3.78264938e-02 c-1.03749274e-02 d4.02516453e-03]", 
                      "[a-2.13926377e-02 b9.27949827e-02 c-5.89836483e-02 d2.44455224e-03]"),
             vec2 = c("[a-4.16121967e-02 b4.51207198e-02 c-7.89282843e-02 d4.02516453e-03]", 
                      "[a-7.40210414e-02 b1.75862815e-02 c-1.03749274e-02 d4.02516453e-03]", 
                      "[a-6.73705637e-02 b9.27949827e-02 c-8.35041553e-02 d2.44455224e-03]"))
```

I'm looking for a fast (the data frame I'm working with contains a lot more and much larger vectors) solution (preferably dplyr) that converts the vector columns into lists with numerical vectors for each row.

So far I managed to remove the unnecessary characters and separate the vector elements by commas like this:

```
mutate(df, 
         vec1 = str_replace_all(vec1, "\\[|\\]|a|b|c|d", ""),
         vec1 = str_replace_all(vec1, " ", ","),
         vec2 = str_replace_all(vec2, "\\[|\\]|a|b|c|d", ""),
         vec2 = str_replace_all(vec2, " ", ","))
```

Maybe there's a better and more elegant solution for this step. While we're at it: I actually wonder how to do this with mutate_at() and starts_with("vec") in order to fix all my columns at once.

More importantly, I'm struggling with the conversion to numeric vectors resulting in 2 list columns with one numerical vector with 4 elements in each row and column. I only managed to extract and convert single vectors like this:

```
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(df[1,'vec1'], ",")))
```

However, I'd like to avoid a loop through all the vectors. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mutate_at` to apply a function to multiple columns, remove characters `[a-d]` and square brackets (`[]`) using `gsub` and convert the vector to numeric to get list columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate_at(vars(vec1:vec2), 
        ~purrr::map(strsplit(gsub('[a-d]|\\[|\\]', '', .), "\\s+"), as.numeric))

#  id                                             vec1
#1  1 -0.04161220, 0.04512072, -0.07892828, 0.00402516
#2  2 -0.07521469, 0.03782649, -0.01037493, 0.00402516
#3  3 -0.02139264, 0.09279498, -0.05898365, 0.00244455

#                                              vec2
#1 -0.04161220, 0.04512072, -0.07892828, 0.00402516
#2 -0.07402104, 0.01758628, -0.01037493, 0.00402516
#3 -0.06737056, 0.09279498, -0.08350416, 0.00244455
```